# Degree of field extension over a fixed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose $L$ is a field and $H$ is a finite subgroup of $Aut(L)$.

Then $[L:L^H]=|H|$

I've seen a proof of this that uses the Rank-Nullity theorem but it's rather cumbersome and difficult to remember the large number of steps required.

Is there a simpler proof of this that perhaps doesn't use the Rank-Nullity theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Every $\alpha$ has a finite orbit under H $\{\sigma_1(\alpha),\ldots,\sigma_r(\alpha)\}$. Then the polynomial
$$\prod (x-\sigma_i(\alpha)) $$
Is in $L^H$. This shows that the extension is separable, normal and every element has degree lower than the cardinality of $H$. So $[L:L^H] $ is finite and given that $H<Gal(L/L^H) $ you have the equality.