# Unpacking a proof that the degree of the field extension $[L:L^H]$ is equal to $|H|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, proof-explanation, galois-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof provided in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754397/degree-of-field-extension-over-a-fixed-field). It goes as follows:

**Theorem**: Let $L$ be a field and let $H$ be a finite subgroup of $\text{Aut}(L)$. If $L^H$ is the fixed field of $H$, then $$[L:L^H]=|H|$$

*Proof*: let $H=\{\sigma_1,\ldots ,\sigma_r\}$. Every $\alpha \in L$ has a finite orbit $\{\sigma_1(\alpha),\ldots ,\sigma_r(\alpha)\}$ under $H$, so the polynomial

$$p(x)=\prod_i \big(x-\sigma_i(\alpha)\big)$$

is in $L^H[x]$. This shows the extension is separable, normal, and that every element $\alpha\in L$ has degree lower or equal than the cardinality of $H$. So $[L:L^H]$ is finite, and given that $H\leq \text{Gal}(L:L^H)$ we have that $[L:L^H]=|H|$.

---

There are a few things I do not understand about this proof:

1. Why is the extension separable? Is it not possible that $\sigma_i(\alpha)=\sigma_j(\alpha)$ for some $i\neq j$?
2. Why is $[L:L^H]$ finite? Just because every element is algebraic over $L^H$ it does not follow that the degree of the extension is finite.
3. Given the above, I can understand why $|H|\leq[L:L^H]$, but how does the proof establish equality?

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer your questions in order.

1. Of course it is
   possible that for some $\sigma,\tau\in H$ the equality
   $\sigma(\alpha)=\tau(\alpha)$ holds.

Let $K=\{\sigma\in H\mid\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha\}$.
It is clear that $K$ is a subgroup of $H$.
Let $H=\sigma_1K\cup\ldots\cup\sigma_kK$ be
the union of different left cosets.
Then $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ are pairwise different.
Hence the minimal polynomial
$$
f(x)=(x-\sigma_1(\alpha))\ldots(x-\sigma_k(\alpha))
$$
of $\alpha$ over $L^H$  has distinct roots.

2. Here it is proved that every element of $L$ has
   degree lower than the cardinality of $H$.
   It follows that the degree of the extension $|L:L^H|$ is finite.
   This follows, for example, from the primitive element theorem.
   If $L^H<L_1$ is separable field extension of finite degree (here $L_1<L$), then it is simple
   $L_1=L^H(\alpha)$. So $|L_1:L^H|\leq|H|$.
   Since $L$ is the union of all such $L_1$, we have $|L:L^H|\leq|H|$.
3. See 2.

I hope I am not mistaken.

Comment: I can see how, after having shown that the extension $L:L^H$ is separable and finite, one can use the primitive element theorem to arrive at $[L:L^H]\leq |H|$, but I'm still puzzled at how you show that the extension is finite. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Certainly the cosets $\sigma _iK$ are parwise disjoint, but could you also explain further how you conclude that the $\sigma _i(\alpha)$ are pairwise different?

Comment: To your first comment.
Which particular point needs clarification?
I have clarified the second point a bit. Is this enough?

To your second comment. If $\sigma_i(\alpha)=\sigma_j(\alpha)$, then
$$
\sigma_j^{-1}\sigma_i(\alpha)=\alpha\
\Rightarrow\ \sigma_j^{-1}\sigma_i\in K\
\Rightarrow\ \sigma_jK=\sigma_iK
\Rightarrow\ i=j.
$$

Comment: Ah I see now why the $\sigma _i$ are distinct. I'm still confused about the last part. Yes, $[L_1:L^H]\leq |H|$ and $L$ is the union of all such $L_1$. How does that imply that $[L:L^H]\leq |H|$?

Comment: If $|L:L^H|>|H|$, then
there are elements
$\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_s\in L$, $s>|H|$ linearly independent over $L^H$.
Let $L_1=L^H(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_s)$.
By the primitive element theorem $L_1=L^H(\alpha)$.
The degree of $\alpha$ is equal to $|L_1:L^H|\geq s>|H|$.
We obtained a contradiction.